# Why do I sometimes get 'sh: $'\302\211 ... ': command not found' in xterm/sh?

Tags: bash, shell, xterm, sh

Sometimes when I simply type a valid command like 'find ...', or anything really, I get back the following, which is completely unexpected and confusing (`...` is command name I type):

```
sh: $'\302\211...': command not found
```

There is some corruption going on I think. I don't use color in my prompt, I am using the Bash shell in POSIX mode as `sh` (`chsh` to `/bin/sh` and so on - `$SHELL` is `sh`).

What is going on and why does this keep happening? Anything I can debug? I think this is more of an `xterm` issue than `sh`, or at least a combination of the two.

#### Files, for context:

My `/etc/profile`, as distributed with Arch Linux x86-64:

```
# /etc/profile

#Set our umask
umask 022

# Set our default path
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
export PATH

# Load profiles from /etc/profile.d
if test -d /etc/profile.d/; then
        for profile in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
                test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
        done
        unset profile
fi

# Source global bash config
if test "$PS1" && test "$BASH" && test -r /etc/bash.bashrc; then
        . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

# Termcap is outdated, old, and crusty, kill it.
unset TERMCAP

# Man is much better than us at figuring this out
unset MANPATH
```

My `/etc/shrc` follows below. It's something I created as a way to have `sh` parse some file on startup, for a non-login shell; it is achieved using `ENV` variable set in `/etc/environment` with the line `ENV=/etc/shrc`:

```
PS1='\u@\H \w \$ '
alias ls='ls -F --color'
alias grep='grep -i --color'
[ -f ~/.shrc ] && . ~/.shrc
```

My `~/.profile`, I am launching X when logging in through first virtual tty:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec xinit -- -dpi 111
```

My `~/.xinitc`, as you can see I am using the system as a Virtual Box guest:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources

VBoxClient-all

awesome &

exec xterm
```

And finally, my `~/.Xresources`, no fancy stuff here I guess:

```
*faceName: Inconsolata
*faceSize: 10
xterm*VT100*translations: #override <Btn1Up>: select-end(PRIMARY, CLIPBOARD, CUT_BUFFER0)

xterm*colorBDMode: true
xterm*colorBD: #ff8000
xterm*cursorColor: S_red
```

Since `~/.profile` references among other things `/etc/bash.bashrc`, here is its content:

```
#
# /etc/bash.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
PS2='> '
PS3='> '
PS4='+ '

case ${TERM} in
  xterm*|rxvt*|Eterm|aterm|kterm|gnome*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
                                                        
    ;;
  screen)
    PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }'printf "\033_%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
    ;;
esac

[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion   ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

I have no idea what that `case` statement does, by the way, it does look a bit suspicious though, but then again, who am I to know.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /bin/sh`? Also, please post your `~/.bashrc`, the problem is probably there. What OS is this? Answers are often OS-dependent. Are you connecting to a remote machine via ssh or is this local? If remote, please post your `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bash_profile` if present.

Comment: I have updated the question with all kinds of file content, I hope it suffices. Output of `ls -l /bin/sh` is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 25 12:06 /bin/sh -> bash*`. I don't have a `~/.bashrc` as I am running the Bash shell in so-called POSIX mode. No `~/.bash_profile` either.

Answer (score 15):

It happens when I first attempt to paste a command from the clipboard, Linux-style (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and when that doesn't work, paste with the mouse. Apparently the keyboard combination inserts an invisible character before the command. The solution is simple, don't use the keyboard to paste, or if you have, press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> before pasting with the mouse.

Comment: Perfect answer! helped me on git bash on windows

Comment: Great.. :) It Working properly....

Answer (score 3):

The `0x89` provides a clue: with the default [`eightBitInput`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) resource setting, `xterm` logically-ORs the input 8-bit codes to map them from 0-127 to 128-255:

- <kbd>tab</kbd> is `^I` is 0x9, and
- ORed with 0x80 gives the odd 0x89.

You can fix the problem by not pressing your "meta" key at the same time you press <kbd>tab</kbd>.

The `eightBitInput` feature is old (dating from X11R4 in 1989), corresponding to the *meta* key feature.  Much later, it was modified to work with UTF-8 in [Patch #183 - 2003/12/26 - XFree86 4.3.99.903](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_183):

> - modify handling of **`eightBitInput`** resource in UTF-8 mode to translate the value into UTF-8. Otherwise an illegal UTF-8 code is sent to the application (report by Bram Moolenaar).

People using `bash` tend to assume that meta mode refers to prefixing things with an escape character, but have it backwards.  See *[Alt-keys do not work in bash](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode)* in the ncurses FAQ.

If you turn `eightBitInput` *off*, that would not solve this particular problem: `xterm` would send <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> when you press <kbd>*meta*</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, which `bash` should object to...

Comment: This helps.  I changed the mitty terminal feture type from `xterm` to `xterm-256` in the options settings of git-bash and the weird codes disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

on my work machine I have a windows and use a git-bash CLI (mintty cygwin) to run commands I would normally run on linux

it happened to me that I got `bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found` after copying-pasting from a power shell window:

```
$ curl -v -F foobar
bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
```

where  was completely invisible to naked eye and looked like `$ curl -v -F foobar`

**so I did remove every whitespace from before my command, like:**

```
$curl -v -F foobar
```

note there are no more whitespaces between `$`

hope this helps someone, cheers

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I had a space in front of my actual command:

```
[admin@centos ~]$ ›  sudo systemctl status rsyslog
 -bash: $'\302\233': command not found
[admin@centos ~]$sudo systemctl status rsyslog
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
```

It must have been a tab character because when I copied and pasted it to this post, a strange character appeared

```
 ›
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the UTF-8 encoding of the "[CHARACTER TABULATION WITH JUSTIFICATION](http://codepoints.net/U+0089)".

I guess you are using a specific keyboard or editor that uses this unusual character instead of the regular tab, which is normally ignored in shell command lines, or having a locale mismatch between the shell and the terminal emulator.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I am following - am I using `%` somewhere? How? I am only using `vim` and `locale` reports all as `en_US.UTF-8` except `LC_ALL` which is not set. Anything I can do to test your assumptions?

Comment: @amn: I am almost sure it is not `‰` but the Unicode character "CHARACTER TABULATION WITH JUSTIFICATION". The code which bash shows is UTF-8 representation (C2 89) of the character (U+0089). I would check if you accidentally do not press some key (TAB?) or key combination before the problem occurs. If you have a suspicion, try the key combination here: `od -ctx1`. After typing the key sequence, press Enter and Ctrl+D.

Comment: Indeed, it is not the common `%` but a control character that also have a graphic representation which is `‰` (per thousand vs percent). Is this happening during interactive shell sessions ? Are you using tab to autocomplete commands ? Is your keyboard providing a `‰` key ?

Comment: No `‰` whatever it is, and the error I described happens seemingly at random. I am not using tab when that happens. No `‰` on the keybord, either. `od -ctx1` tells me `sh: $'\302\211\302\211\302\211od': command not found` - I think we're getting somewhere!

Comment: Is the issue still present when using a different terminal emulator ? When connecting remotely from another machine ?

Comment: No, only when running `sh` in `xterm`...

Comment: Then use bash/ksh93/zsh/whatever in gnome-terminal/konsole/terminator/whatever and problem fixed ...

Comment: The graphical representation ‰ is a red herring here. The character is a control character probably produced by typing Alt-Tab, and it just happens to map to the per-mille glyph ([U+2030](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2030/index.htm)) in Windows code page 1252.  See perhaps also https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#89

Comment: @tripleee You are right. I removed reference to  ‰ which was an artifact.

Answer (score 1):

This solve the problem:

```
setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"
```

Comment: It might be useful to say what this actually does, and how it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that worked for me in Git Bash, probably works for more terminals if you find the corresponding settings.

You may need to enable usage of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>-shortcuts.

1. Find your terminals Settings.

   In Git Bash, Right click the windows title bar and select **Options...**
2. Go to **Keys**.
3. Under **Shortcuts**, tick the checkbox for ***Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts***.
4. Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> or <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

This is only a solution if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to copy terminal text, or any other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> combination.

It seems to insert, e.g. the `\302\203`, when using them. It was not the pasted value, or even the pasting shortcut itself that did this for me.

Your issue may be something else. Make sure your bash_profile PS1 configuration is well formatted, if you have any configuration there (e.g. to set custom/colored prompt, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The shell is interpreting invisible characters and complaining about them, similar to what jlliagre was saying in his answer mentioning [CHARACTER TABULATION WITH JUSTIFICATION](https://codepoints.net/U+0089).

If you have not typed any invisible characters, then the shell is getting some data elsewhere and misconstruing it as input. In other words, it's a bug. You should report it to the maintainers of the terminal emulator you are using.

(I realize this question is four years old now, but this may help someone else.)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had strange characters in the command or the script.

What worked for me was to remove the extra lines at the end of my `~/.bash_profile` file. There was also some white space and to be sure I executed `unix2dos ~/.bash_profile`.

I am using Git Bash with Mintty 3.4.3.