# bash: $'\302\211[COMMAND]': command not found

Tags: bash, debian, keyboard, xterm

I've used bash in xterm on Debian Jessie for about 2 years. Just recently I sometimes get an error `bash: $'\302\211[COMMAND]': command not found`.

The only help I can find on the topic is [Piping grep causes error `$'\302\240grep': command not found` on linux](/q/878482) and [Why do I sometimes get `sh: $'\302\211 … ': command not found` in xterm/sh?](/q/670867). This sometimes happens when I type <kbd>tab</kbd> for command completion. Is there any way I can get rid of this without switching terminal emulators?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as *[Why do I sometimes get 'sh: $'\302\211 … ': command not found' in xterm/sh?](https://superuser.com/questions/670867/why-do-i-sometimes-get-sh-302-211-command-not-found-in-xterm-sh/1123368#1123368)* (but not a duplicate — yet — because there was no suitable answer).

Summarizing from my answer: you see this behavior because occasionally you press <kbd>*meta*</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> rather than just <kbd>tab</kbd>, which makes `xterm` send a different character.

Answer (score -2):

This solve the problem:

```
setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"
```

Comment: When you find an exact duplicate, please flag or vote to close as such, rather than posting the same answer in both places. It would also be nice if you would explain how this fixes the issue.

Comment: Also, it doesn't: bash: $'\302\203\302\226\302\226setxkbmap': command not found